# How to insert a ResultSet into a new MYSQL table?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to insert the result of execution of a MYSQL query into another MYSQL table. Following is the code snippet:

```
rs1 = st.executeQuery(query1);
while(rs1.next()){
    insertData(species,rs1,"try");      
}
```

The resultset `rs1` contains n number of rows returned as a result of execution of `query1`. I am trying to insert all rows in `rs1` into another table. Insertion operation is carried out in the function `insertData()` as follows:

```
public void insertData(String species, ResultSet rs, String table)throws Exception{
    String q = "Insert into "+table+" values("+rs.getFloat("sl")+","+rs.getFloat("sw")+","+rs.getFloat("pl")+","+rs.getFloat("pw")+",'"+rs.getString("classification")+"')";
    int x = st.executeUpdate(q);
    if( x == 0)
        System.out.println("Error inserting data");
}
```

After I run the code, I get the following exception:

`Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed`

As far as I know, `rs1.next()` points the cursor to the first row in the first iteration.

Please correct me if I am missing something fundamental here.

Comment: what is your insertData()?  can you post it?

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: please see my answer below

Comment: Your code in `insertData` is susceptible to SQL injection. Please use a prepared statement instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an open one exists.

Quoted from [Statement Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)

You use the same `Statement st` object execute different queries twice.

```
rs1 = st.executeQuery(query1); // executed before while loop
int x = st.executeUpdate(q);  // executed in while loop
```

When you execute  `st.executeUpdate(q);` in your `insertData()` method, `ResultSet` rs1 is closed. You need to create a new Statement and execute the second query.